# Fake torus triangulation in Munkres

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

It's mentioned in Elements of algebraic topology (Munkres) that the following figure is not a valid triangulation of torus because it "does more than paste opposite edges together".

[image]

> Q: What's wrong with this triangulation?